# Why is my ResultSet becoming empty when returned from method?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have put the querying part in a separate function which handles try,catch and connection in one place. Recently i started seeing that the result set returned is empty but within the method it is not empty. Is this an improper way of passing result set?

```
public synchronized ResultSet executeQry(String query) {
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, user, pass);
        Class.forName(myDriver);
        Statement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        System.out.println("executing query: " + query);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("result set is empty?" + resultSetEmpty(rs));
        return rs;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am calling this method like so

`ResultSet tableDataRS = executeQry("SELECT * FROM dummy_table");
System.out.println("tableData is empty? :"+resultSetEmpty(tableDataRS));`

When run, the log shows that within executeQry the result set is not empty but once returned it is empty

`executing query: SELECT * FROM dummy_table
result set is empty?false
tableDataRS is empty? :true`

Comment: Well what does `resultSetEmpty` do? My guess is that it reads to the end of the result set - at which point, if you try to read it again (without taking care to reset it or anything similar) it *will* be empty.

Comment: To put it another way, suppose you filled a car's fuel tank with petrol and asked "How far will it go before running out of petrol?" twice in a row without refilling it, the first answer might be hundreds of miles, and the second answer would be "nowhere"...

Comment: Can you share the contents of `resultSetEmpty`?

Comment: @jonskeet Yes my method "resultSetEmpty" is missing "rs.beforeFirst();". One of the commits replaced this method with its early version. I added it and now it works. Thanks

Comment: Better post it as an answer, and not as edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comments, i found the issue. I am moving the cursor from before start of content of result set to check if it is empty in the method "**resultSetEmpty()**" so when i later actually tried to use it, it was already pointing to the end so there is no content to use. This can be fixed by adding "**beforeFirst()**" to result set. Here is the method edited with the method call to move cursor to before the first record.

```
public Boolean resultSetEmpty(ResultSet rs) {
    boolean isEmpty = true;
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            isEmpty = false;
            rs.beforeFirst();
            break;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isEmpty;
}
```

Comment: Using `beforeFirst()` will break on a `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` result sets. Why do you even want or need to check if your result set is empty? Also note that the way your `executeQry` method works, you are leaking your connection and statement. You need to take proper care of those objects and close them properly when you are done with them.